# ng-disabled on a button and invalidating a form in Angular

Tags: angularjs, forms, invalidation, angularjs-ng-form

I have a form with 2 input boxes and below it are 2 radio buttons and few more input boxes under the radio buttons.

By default, only the first 2 input boxes above the radio buttons are required. Once I've populated the 2 input boxes, the form will become valid (myForm.$invalid becomes false). Now when I click the 2nd radio button, the other input boxes will become required making the myForm.$invalid true again. If I click back the first radio button, the form becomes valid again.

Assuming 2nd radio button is selected and we've populated all the input boxes, I want the form to finally become valid. I need this so I can change the ng-disabled of a button.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Ok, forget everything I wrote above, I over-complicated this for nothing!

The simplest solution fits your scenario, you'll use `ng-required`. Example:

```
False<input type="radio" name="response" data-ng-model="myRadioButtonModel" data-ng-value="false" />
True<input type="radio" name="response" data-ng-model="myRadioButtonModel" data-ng-value="true" />
       <br/>
<input name="myTextInput" type="text" ng-model="textInput" ng-required="myRadioButtonModel === true"/>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bEkLIMJH4aY9K1RoAwvZ?p=preview)

Comment: Very cool! I'm going to try my best to implement your solution. Plunker would help me a lot :)

Comment: @devwannabe I'll try to compose one soon when I have some time, I'll update :)

Comment: @devwannabe Maybe we're not on the same page. The submit button becomes disabled if the radio button is "True" and the text input is empty. If the radio button is false you can leave it empty. So it's only mandatory if the radio button is true. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: I tried both setting to false and true but the submit button doesn't get disabled on the plunker I tried above.

Comment: oh, I just tested it. It's working. Let me try once more

Comment: my form is working great now! The $watch got triggered now too while watching $valid :D Thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: I'm going to dissect your code to learn it more. :) The code in your directive specifically the parse is advance for me right now, hehehe.

Comment: @devwannabe Notice that I'm not using the directive anymore, I forgot to remove it after I changed the approach :)

Comment: Yup, I noticed it when I looked at my template again. :)